# Auto-generated patch fails to apply (wrong paths)

Tags: vcpkg

I've tried to follow:

https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/blob/master/docs/examples/patching.md

On Windows
seems like one needs to use something along the lines of

```
git diff --ignore-space-at-eol > ..\..\..\..\ports\libssh\use-onconnection-bind-callback.patch
```

to generate the patch.

Then, the resulting patch has something along the lines to be seen below:

```
diff --git a/0.9.5-16f77da2ad.clean/compile_commands.json b/0.9.5-16f77da2ad.clean/compile_commands.json
index fe0bdd4..ae0d51d 120000
--- a/0.9.5-16f77da2ad.clean/compile_commands.json
+++ b/0.9.5-16f77da2ad.clean/compile_commands.json
```

Now, after modifying the portfile.cmake:

```
vcpkg_extract_source_archive_ex(
    OUT_SOURCE_PATH SOURCE_PATH
    ARCHIVE ${ARCHIVE}
    REF ${VERSION}
    PATCHES
    "use-onconnection-bind-callback.patch"
)
```

and trying to recompile (vpckg install)
I'm getting the following error, seemingly related to wrong paths.

```
CMake Error at scripts/cmake/z_vcpkg_apply_patches.cmake:57 (message):
  Applying patch failed: Checking patch
  0.9.5-16f77da2ad.clean/compile_commands.json...

  error: 0.9.5-16f77da2ad.clean/compile_commands.json: No such file or
  directory

  Checking patch 0.9.5-16f77da2ad.clean/src/bind.c...
```

I've tried to trace (through sys-calls) files that are tried to be accessed but I don't relly know which executable directly attempts to do so (seems like it's neither vcpkg.exe nor cmake.exe) so that I could correct these within the patch file.

Ideas?

**Update**
After I've managed to come up with  appropriate paths (by removing the folder prefix and executing from C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\vcpkg\buildtrees\libssh\src>) thus a sample fragment of the corrected patch file now looks like:

```
diff --git a/src/bind.c b/src/bind.c
index fa8df9e..fe39ced 100644
--- a/src/bind.c
+++ b/src/bind.c
```

, things began getting hilarious:

```
Building package libssh[core,crypto,mbedtls]:x64-windows...
-- Using cached C:/Users/Administrator/Documents/vcpkg/downloads/libssh-0.9.5.tar.xz
-- Extracting source C:/Users/Administrator/Documents/vcpkg/downloads/libssh-0.9.5.tar.xz
-- Applying patch use-onconnection-bind-callback.patch CMake Error at scripts/cmake/vcpkg_extract_source_archive_ex.cmake:150 (file):   file RENAME failed to rename

    C:/Users/Administrator/Documents/vcpkg/buildtrees/libssh/src/0.9.5-c237aa395b.tmp/libssh-0.9.5

  to

    C:/Users/Administrator/Documents/vcpkg/buildtrees/libssh/src/0.9.5-c237aa395b.clean

  because: No error

Call Stack (most recent call first):   ports/libssh/portfile.cmake:10 (vcpkg_extract_source_archive_ex)   scripts/ports.cmake:142 (include)
```

**Update 2** The second error seems to be related to https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues/8199

and occurs randomly.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else these are the steps to follow (works on Windows) with the sample case of 'libssh'. Be prepare to recompile a couple of times due to the bug in vcpkg referenced above.

**Step 1**) First cd into "vcpkg\buildtrees\libssh\src\0.9.5-16f77da2ad.clean"

**Step 2**)
execute
"git diff --ignore-space-at-eol > ........\ports\libssh\use-onconnection-bind-callback.patch"

**Step 3**) edit "use-onconnection-bind-callback.patch"
there, clear occurances of "0.9.5-16f77da2ad.clean/"

**Step 4**) cd into   "\vcpkg\buildtrees\libssh\src>"
and execute "vcpkg install libssh:x64-windows"